# STM32 Custom Bootloader Jump to Application

Tags: stm32, bootloader

I wrote a custom bootloader for the STM32F4 microcontroller and I'm able to write an application to the flash memory at the address of 0x08008000. The issue I have is when I use the jump function the application doesn't seem to execute. I have attached the jump function below. I have disabled all the peripherals, timers and interrupts. Also, relocated the vector table to 0x08008000 to run the new app.

```
void bootloader_jump_to_user_app(void)
{

   //just a function pointer to hold the address of the reset handler of the user app.
    void (*app_reset_handler)(void);

    //shut down any tasks running
    HAL_GPIO_DeInit(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_10);
    HAL_GPIO_DeInit(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_11);
    HAL_TIM_Base_Stop_IT(&htim4);
    HAL_TIM_Base_DeInit(&htim4);
    HAL_RCC_DeInit();
    HAL_DeInit();


    SysTick->CTRL = 0;
    SysTick->LOAD = 0;
    SysTick->VAL = 0;

    //disbale interuppts
    __set_PRIMASK(1);
    __disable_irq();

     SCB->VTOR = FLASH_SECTOR2_BASE_ADDRESS; //0x080080000

    // 1. configure the MSP by reading the value from the base address of the sector 2
    uint32_t msp_value = *(__IO uint32_t *)FLASH_SECTOR2_BASE_ADDRESS;

    __set_MSP(msp_value);

    uint32_t resethandler_address = *(__IO uint32_t *) (FLASH_SECTOR2_BASE_ADDRESS + 4);

    app_reset_handler = (void*) resethandler_address;

    //3. jump to reset handler of the user application
    app_reset_handler();

}
```

In the linker file for the bootloader I have broken the flash into two parts, one for the app and the other for the bootloader. For the application linker file I have the flash starting at 0x08008000.

```
/* Memories definition */
MEMORY
{
    CCMRAM  (xrw)   : ORIGIN = 0x10000000,  LENGTH = 64K
    RAM (xrw)   : ORIGIN = 0x20000000,  LENGTH = 128K
    FLASH   (rx)    : ORIGIN = 0x8000000,   LENGTH = 128K
    APPLICATION (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x08008000, LENGTH = 896K
}
```

Comment: How/where is `FLASH_SECTOR2_BASE_ADDRESS` defined? Is it just an integer or is it already a pointer of some sort?

Comment: defined in header file as #define FLASH_SECTOR2_BASE_ADDRESS 0x08008000U

Comment: I have an STM32F4 bootloader which does something like:
`extern uint32_t __FLASH_segment_start__[];
#define APPLICATION_START (uint32_t)__FLASH_segment_start__
SCB->VTOR = (uint32_t)APPLICATION_START;
__set_MSP(APPLICATION_START[0]);
((void (*)(void))APPLICATION_START[1])();`
and it seems like your code _should have the same effect ...

Comment: code seems similar. Maybe there's something that i missed since my jump function doesnt work

Comment: Try adding one to the jump address. The jump target code has to be Thumb, which is set by the lower address bit.

Comment: It may be also nicer to do the jump in assembly as a C call is subject to ABI conventions that are undesirable here.

Comment: is this what you meant by adding one to jump address:app_reset_handler = (void*) resethandler_address+1

Comment: Did you link your code to start at 0x08008000? You can't just take an image linked for a different start address, load it, and expect it to work.

Comment: Do you realise that a Cortex image starts with the SP and PC values, not with executable code?

Comment: You could look the code of the STM32Duino , it has a bootloader for the Arduino clone.

Comment: Yes i linked my code to start at 0x08008000 by changing the flash start address of the application code and the vector offset to 0x8000.

Comment: Disregard my idea about adding 1. It should be already in the reset vector. You just need to attach a debugger and look at all values before the jump.

Comment: you cant simply do that with a cortex-m and expect it to work it depends on how the compiler implements that call as to whether or not you need the lsbit set, so you have to look the disassemble, and yes with the same compiler it can change and still be wrong.  much easier to use one or two lines of asm and be insured that it will work  now and in the future when you re-build this project.  .globl HOP; HOP: bx r0 or you can .globl HOP; HOP: orr r0,#1; bx r0  there are already asked and answere SO questions on this topic with examples of how/why these didnt work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get the bootloader to work. I just needed to rename the reset_handler in the linker script and startup_stm32F40xx.s file to bootloader_reset_handler for the bootloader program.

Comment: Can you please tell me how you renamed reset_handler in the linker script and startup_stm32F40xx.s file

Answer (score 0):

Renaming reset_handler in the linker script and startup_stm32F40xx.s file

1. Open STM32XXXXX_FLASH.ld file in your project search text Reset_Handler. replace this text with Boot_Reset_Handler.
2. Open startup_stm32F40xx.s file in startup folder search text Reset_Handler. replace this text with Boot_Reset_Handler for all occurances.